# Combining dependency injection with service locator

Tags: flutter, dart, dependency-injection, architecture, service-locator

In the following example, a service locator is used to inject dependencies over classes. Is that in any way better approach than resolving dependencies within the class and keep the initialiser (or class interface) clean?

```
class MyClass {
    let service: Service
    init(service: Service) {
        self.service = service
    }
}

class RootClass {
    func something() {
        let myClass = MyClass(service: ServiceLocator.shared.resolve())
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not flutter code?

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the way to register and inject

```
// Register a class 
locator.registerFactory(() => Service());

class Service {}

class MyClass {
  final Service service;

  MyClass({this.service});
 }

class RootClass {
 void something() {

  final myClass = MyClass(service: locator.get());
 }
```

}